# React + TS. Cannot use union keys as index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks, union-types

I got a hook with useState and delete method to manage my form values.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState<tAllValues>({});
```

My values would be:

```
{
  name: 'Andrew',
  age: 34,
  avatar: [{
    name: 'avatar.png',
    size: 45234,
    ...
  }]
}
```

These values can be from all forms so have tAllValues type which is union of all form types.

```
type tForm1 = { name: string; age: number; };
type tForm2 = { avatar: File };

type tAllValues = tForm1 | tForm2;
```

I need to have a delete method to delete file. File is normal object in values and here is my method:

```
  const deleteFile = (fileId: string, fieldName: KeysOfUnion<tAllValues>) => {
    const fieldValue = values[fieldName];
    const filteredFiles = fieldValue.filter((value) => value.id !== fileId);
    setValues({ ...values, [fieldName]: filteredFiles });
  };
```

fieldName have type KeysOfUnion because it need to be one of keys from tAllValues and here is a problem.

```
export type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
```

I can see that fieldName is **'name' | 'age' | 'avatar'**  but I got a TypeScript error:

```
 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"name" | "age" | "avatar"' can't be used to index type 'tAllValues'.Property 'name' does not exist on type 'tAllValues'.ts(7053)
```

This happens probably because there is no 'name' in tForm2 type but it is in intForm1 type.

Is the way TS help to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accept all keys of the union, instead accept only the keys of the object you know you are manipulating. So purify the function by passing in `values` as a parameter, then use a generic to obtain the type of `v`.

```js
const deleteFile = <T extends tAllValues>(v: T, fileId: string, fieldName: keyof T) => {
  const fieldValue = v[fieldName];
  const filteredFiles = fieldValue.filter((value) => value.id !== fileId);
  //^ ERROR: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'T[keyof T]'
};
```

However this still has an error, since you could use any fieldValue and return a value that is not an array. So you get another error. You can narrow this by checking if it is an array.

```js
if (Array.isArray(fieldValue)) {
  const filteredFiles = fieldValue.filter((value) => value.id !== fileId);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+jAvDA3gKBjMBDAtgUwC4YByAQTABMAnfAdxIBoMZsBzImAZgBZnNsAN2xRs1YgG10mTDgLESQkWIB0ABzBsmLTBACWAL048ArACZe-GAF8Aummto0UAJ5r8MKADEQ1XAEYkVCw8TmhqPU0AblYOYjAAV1wAI3xqGOso5zcPb19cMyCUVmFRcRgvPQAbD0ynV3dPMiqqgDVsKoT8CCC8v0CAH08fPzMstFBIWGFO7uIoZraOrp7kFGtWHuwwF2zGqG7YZAb8EAAzGBmVtAB6G8wAPQB+PdzDwuQAa3wXc89D273GDPJyTaAwSj4GoHSo1IIAHgAKjB8AAPA5UHoLFrtWYQAB8AApBMREYwYGdqvgAJKUYjhSJscmUqGUAByoWI31+F0RAEokPjUCwwbAWVVKLiukFBBJxezQrYsphRRTqgdaJRYd0gvKpfgVJSqhrCcTlvgBYghVcDXpKDAAISIZBGmmUPlZOpoNFqXywE4wADSPwgAHkzgBVMB6cBIoXIZFojGULY7GBPGDcv7I+L4QRpcaqyHQ-Daj4wJEo9H4TFNHHmgnE0nMqm0+lQCKaFusjnyTM-bOWoXSGCqvXmmVyvQ9xXKmB6C6EsjUajYFwqPQQZerlyE8ezPkCkcq8Dgo0a-BaqmrNWs-WG9VpU02oeXc0b+1Ol2t91zxyZIA)